# What are the risks of Composer running as root ?

Tags: composer-php, webserver, file-permissions

I don't understand the difference between composer running as root vs non-root user. Whatever user you run as, you must have to give write access to the main dir where composer stores its assets like vendor, scripts, composer.json and composer.lock.

E.g in my case, my dir structures are like below:-

```
.test
|-scripts
|-composer.json
|-scripts
|-webroot
|-.env
```

Say I am running as non-root user, But I must need to give that user to `rwx` to **test** dir so that whenever I run composer install it can create vendor, composer.lock and read scripts and execute it inside test dir. 
But once you give rwx it can create any malicious script inside it or may access my env file. So how does it matter if you run as root or non-root ?

Answer (score 0):

After spending some more time, I got to know that as composer is a cli script it uses PHP-CLI not PHP-FPM interpreter. PHP-CLI & PHP-FPM both are different thing. Web Server talks to PHP-FPM not to PHP-CLI. So whenever we call composer  the composer process is owned by the PHP-CLI owner.

So webroot should be owned by the PHP-FPM owner to make a website work, where composer.json, vendors etc should be owned by the PHP-CLI owner. Both user should be different. Infact test dir should be writable by PHP-CLI owner and not writable by PHP-FPM process owner. Often PHP-FPM is run as owner www-data